# Secret is not creating in AKS after fetching it with CSI Driver

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, csi

By using the reference of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/csi-secrets-store-nginx-tls this document, I'm trying to fetch the TLS secrets from AKV to AKS pods.
Initially I created and configured **CSI driver configuration** with using **User Assigned Managed Identity**.

I have performed the following steps:

- Create AKS Cluster with 1 nodepool.
- Create AKV.
- Created user assigned managed identity and assign it to the nodepool i.e. to the VMSS created for AKS.
- Installed CSI Driver helm chart in AKS's **"kube-system"** namespace. and completed all the requirement to perform this operations.
- Created the TLS certificate and key.
- By using TLS certificate and key, created .pfx file.
- Uploaded that .pfx file in the AKV certificates named as **"ingresscert"**.
- Created new namespace in AKS named as "ingress-test".
- Deployed secretProviderClass in that namespace are as follows.:

```
apiVersion: secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io/v1
kind: SecretProviderClass
metadata:
  name: azure-tls
spec:
  provider: azure
  secretObjects:                            # secretObjects defines the desired state of synced K8s secret objects
  - secretName: ingress-tls-csi
    type: kubernetes.io/tls
    data: 
    - objectName: ingresscert
      key: tls.key
    - objectName: ingresscert
      key: tls.crt
  parameters:
    usePodIdentity: "false"
    useVMManagedIdentity: "true"
    userAssignedIdentityID: "7*******-****-****-****-***********1"
    keyvaultName: "*****-*****-kv"                 # the name of the AKV instance
    objects: |
      array:
        - |
          objectName: ingresscert
          objectType: secret
    tenantId: "e*******-****-****-****-***********f"                    # the tenant ID of the AKV instance
```

- Deployed the **nginx-ingress-controller** helm chart in the same namespace, where certificates are binded with application.
- Deployed the Busy Box deployment are as follows:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: busybox-one
  labels:
    app: busybox-one
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: busybox-one
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: busybox-one
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: busybox
          image: k8s.gcr.io/e2e-test-images/busybox:1.29-1
          command:
            - "/bin/sleep"
            - "10000"
          volumeMounts:
            - name: secrets-store-inline
              mountPath: "/mnt/secrets-store"
              readOnly: true
      volumes:
        - name: secrets-store-inline
          csi:
            driver: secrets-store.csi.k8s.io
            readOnly: true
            volumeAttributes:
              secretProviderClass: "azure-tls"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: busybox-one
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - port: 80
  selector:
    app: busybox-one
```

- Check secret is created or not by using command

```
kubectl get secret -n <namespaceName>
```

**One thing to notice here is, if I attach shell with the busy box pod and go to the mount path which I provided to mount secrets I have seen that secrets are successfully fetched there. But this secrets are not showing in the AKS's secret list.**

I have troubleshooted all the AKS,KV and manifest files but not found anything.
IF there is anything I have missed or anyone has solution for this please let me know.

Thanks in advance..!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i added this as a new answer, bcs the formatting was bad in the comments:

As you are using the Helm chart, you have to activate the secret sync in the `values.yaml` of the Helm Chart:

```
secrets-store-csi-driver:
  syncSecret:
    enabled: true
```

I would still recommend to use the `csi-secrets-store-provider-azure` as AKS Addon instead of the Helm-Chart

Comment: It is working..! After enabling the syncSecret. Thank you so much for your help..!

Comment: @Philip how do you set this setting when using the AKS addon ?

Comment: seems its not needed for the addon according to the documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/csi-secrets-store-driver#sync-mounted-content-with-a-kubernetes-secret

Answer (score 1):

Your config looks good to me. One thing to consider is, that the `User Assigned Managed Identity` should not be the one you created for the AKS, it should be the managed identity from your nodepool (kubelet) and it also needs permission on the AKV.

I had the same issues while using the wrong Managed identity.

`userAssignedIdentityID = Kubelet Client Id ( Nodepool Managed Idendity )`

**AZ CLI**

```
export KUBE_ID=$(az aks show -g <resource group> -n <aks cluster name> --query identityProfile.kubeletidentity.objectId -o tsv)
export AKV_ID=$(az keyvault show -g <resource group> -n <akv name> --query id -o tsv)
az role assignment create --assignee $KUBE_ID --role "Key Vault Secrets Officer" --scope $AKV_ID
```

Comment: As you said, I have provided user assigned managed identity to AKS node pool i.e. to VMSS. and grant access permission to access AKV also. I did it already. Forget to update it in question.
However I also performed this whole thing with Azure CLI also and using PowerShell also. But it is not creating AKS secret.

Comment: when you are using the Azure CLI, i would recommend to not use the Helm Chart bcs the `Secrets CSI Driver`is available as a Addon now. -> `az aks enable-addons --addons azure-keyvault-secrets-provider --name myAKSCluster --resource-group myResourceGroup`